# Showing active language flag

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm using WPML and his switcher to change the languages of the site. Everything works fine so far except the active language flag isn't changed to show the current language.

This is the code I've written so far. It is just always showing the first flag and doesn't change it to active one.

```
<?php
if(function_exists('icl_get_languages')):
    $languages = icl_get_languages('skip_missing=0');
    if(count($languages) >= 1):
?>
        <div class="topbar-lang-switcher">
            <ul class="lang-switcher-polylang"> 
<?php 
        foreach((array)$languages as $language):            
?>
                <li class="current-lang"> 
                    <a rel="alternate" hreflang="<?php echo $language['language_code']; ?>" href="<?php echo $language['url']; ?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo $language['country_flag_url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $language['native_name']; ?>" title="<?php echo $language['native_name']; ?>" />
                    <span><?php echo $language['language_code']; ?>  </span>  
                    </a> 
                </li>
<?php
        endforeach;
?>
            </ul>
        </div>
<?php
    endif;
endif;
?>
```

Can someone help with how to change the flag to the current active language?

Comment: And – what is the actual _question_ now?

Comment: If someone can help and point me how to show the active language

Comment: So how does that get determined, which variable or property tells you which language is the active one?

Comment: Having `class="current-lang"` on _all_ of those list items is probably not what’s needed here to begin with, I am guessing.

Comment: I forgot to delete this class `class="current-lang"`. Was there for testing purpose but doesn't do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to WPML's official [documentation](https://wpml.org/documentation/getting-started-guide/language-setup/custom-language-switcher/), the `icl_get_languages()` function returns an array of languages having the following format:

```
Array
(
 [en] => Array
  (
   [id] => 1
   [active] => 1
   [native_name] => English
   [missing] => 0
   [translated_name] => English
   [language_code] => en
   [country_flag_url] => http://yourdomain/wpmlpath/res/flags/en.png
   [url] => http://yourdomain/about
  )

 [fr] => Array
  (
   [id] => 4
   [active] => 0
   [native_name] => Français
   [missing] => 0
   [translated_name] => French
   [language_code] => fr
   [country_flag_url] => http://yourdomain/wpmlpath/res/flags/fr.png
   [url] => http://yourdomain/fr/a-propos
  )

 [it] => Array
  (
   [id] => 27
   [active] => 0
   [native_name] => Italiano
   [missing] => 0
   [translated_name] => Italian
   [language_code] => it
   [country_flag_url] => http://yourdomain/wpmlpath/res/flags/it.png
   [url] => http://yourdomain/it/circa
  )
)
```

There is the `active` field, which states the current language. So you can have something like:

```php
...
        foreach((array)$languages as $language):            
?>
                <li <?php echo ($language['active'] == 1) ? 'class="current-lang"' : '' ?>> 
                    <a rel="alternate" hreflang="<?php echo $language['language_code']; ?>" href="<?php echo $language['url']; ?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo $language['country_flag_url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $language['native_name']; ?>" title="<?php echo $language['native_name']; ?>" />
                    <span><?php echo $language['language_code']; ?>  </span>  
                    </a> 
                </li>
<?php
        endforeach;
...
```

This way only the active (current) language's `<li>` will have the `current-lang` class. All you need afterwards is to apply the right CSS.